# Check and Return Value in Mysqli_query

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

I am Android developer and trying to make one API for register user using PHP and Mysqli. I have made API like below

```
<?php 
    include("dbconnection.php");
    $email= $_GET['email'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email='".$email."'");
    if (!$query){
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
       $response='success';
    }else{
       $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(email)VALUES ('".$email."')";
       if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          $response='success';
       }else {
          $response='error';
       }
    } 
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

basically I am passing email as parameter like example.com/login?=abc@gmail.com
and I want check that email is already in database table or not. if email exist in database I want return user_id in response and if email is not in database than I want add that email in database and want return user_id. I have made API is working fine as I require but I do not know how to return user_id located with that email. Let me know if someone can give me idea to solve my puzzle. Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: what is `user_id` ? is it autoincrement value ?

Comment: @Ravi yes...its primary key called user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will create an array with message and user_id.

```
 include("dbconnection.php");
    $email= $_GET['email'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE email='".$email."'");
    if (!$query){
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
       // assign message to response array
       $response['message']='success';
       // Get the results data
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
          // assign user_id to response array
          $response['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
       }
    }else{
       $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(email) VALUES ('".$email."')";
       if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          $response['message']='success';
          // assign last inserted id to response array
          $response['user_id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
       }else {
          $response['message']='error';
       }
    } 
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Prepared statements help you secure your SQL statements from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks ....its working fine for add new record. But if email is exist its giving me error called Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in "while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {". Thanks

Comment: These queries are insecure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `PreparedStatement` to avoid sql injection.

Then, second you can use **[`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/pdo.lastinsertid)**

Comment: This answer starts to give good advice but doesn't really follow through with much generosity.  A shame that I cannot UV it.